# cx_freeze is not applying my icon

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I can't seem to add my icon to the executable. I thought maybe my 256 was too large so I had sized it down to a 64 but that didn't seem to be the problem.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what icon is? I was hoping that my app.exe in the folder would have the icon.ico picture, instead it has the following:
[image: default icon].

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
               Executable('SectionAnalysisTool.py',
                          icon="icon64.ico",
                          base=base)
]
includefiles = ["icon.ico"]

setup(name='name',
      version='0.0',
      description='description',
      author = "author",
      options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
      executables=executables
      )
```

I am using Windows 7, WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.5Qt5 (I did not build the app through Qt), and I am using the cx_Freeze provided by WinPython. If it matters, I made the icon through snagit

Comment: Do you have any output from the build process? You can try processing the addition of the icon manually using cx_Freeze.util.AddIcon(exeName, iconName).

Answer (score 2):

You are including `icon.ico` whereas calling icon file `icon64.ico` !
They should be same.
Another thing is that do check whether the image file is actually `.ico` file or not. If not, you can convert the image online.

Hope that helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It happened to when I changed `.png` to `.ico` without convertor but by changing extension. When I used a convertor it started to work for me. So try to use a convertor.